# pandas dropping rows based on datetime condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am dropping rows based on a datetime condition, I have it working with the following line

`df.drop(df[df.index.date == datetime(2017,9,14).date()].index, inplace=True)`

However when I actually run the code I am not passing a `datetime(2017,9,14).date()` for comparison I am passing a `datetime.date(2017,9,14)` . So the code would look something like this...

`df.drop(df[df.index.date == datetime.date(2017,9,14)].index, inplace=True)`

but that obviously throws a error :

"descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'"

what would be the best way to fix this problem to be able to compare dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify code - select all rows if not `datetime.date(2017,9,14)` - so it remove rows with `datetime.date(2017,9,14)`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-09-13', periods=10, freq='10H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
                     a
2017-09-13 00:00:00  0
2017-09-13 10:00:00  1
2017-09-13 20:00:00  2
2017-09-14 06:00:00  3
2017-09-14 16:00:00  4
2017-09-15 02:00:00  5
2017-09-15 12:00:00  6
2017-09-15 22:00:00  7
2017-09-16 08:00:00  8
2017-09-16 18:00:00  9

import datetime
df1 = df[df.index.date != datetime.date(2017,9,14)]
print (df1)
                     a
2017-09-13 00:00:00  0
2017-09-13 10:00:00  1
2017-09-13 20:00:00  2
2017-09-15 02:00:00  5
2017-09-15 12:00:00  6
2017-09-15 22:00:00  7
2017-09-16 08:00:00  8
2017-09-16 18:00:00  9
```

Comment: throws the same error : descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'.  When looking farther into it df.index.date is a NP array and datetime.date is a object.  I think this is the issue?

Comment: @blonc - What is `print (df.index.dtype)` ?

Comment: it is a ```datetime64[ns]```

Comment: appreciate the link to other question.  thanks for help, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown by `datetime.date(2017,9,14)`, it has nothing to do with Pandas.

Try:

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.date(2017,9,14)
```

Throws:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8658ce936e92> in <module>
----> 1 datetime.date(2017,9,14)

TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

but:

```py
import datetime
datetime.date(2017,9,14)
```

works and it also works in your code.